# How to put a runnable into bundle?

Tags: android, runnable, serializable

I want to pass a Runnable into an activity via bundle, so that runnable must run when onCreate fires. I wrote a class which implements Serializable but it causes exception: `"java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object"`.
My code goes here:

```
package some.company.common;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class SerializedRunnable implements Serializable, Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6641813629033240205L;

    public SerializedRunnable() {
    }

    private Runnable runnable;

    public SerializedRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.runnable.run();
    }

}
```

Comment: it is just the contents of the object that are serialized. Why do you want to serialize a runnable, which looks to be a waste. you can always pass just the data to another runnable that will take this data and process

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Runnable is not serializable. To implement your own serialization you must implement `readObject` and `writeObject` by yourself.

Check [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45)

Comment: I added two methods just like this:

 `private void readObject(ObjectInputStream aInputStream)
   throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

  aInputStream.defaultReadObject();
 }

 private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream aOutputStream)
   throws IOException {
  aOutputStream.defaultWriteObject();
 }`

but the same error continues.